# Restart Ubuntu from SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote-desktop, restart

I'm connected through SSH to a machine running Xubuntu, where I'm not sudoed. I would like to somehow restart the OS there, because I'm having troubles with Remote Desktop access to the same machine, hopefully that fixes it.

What could I do, and how?

I'm running Ubuntu on Windows 10 to SSH.

Comment: `systemctl reboot` should work

Comment: Will this reboot Linux for all the users who SSH with ssh specific_user@shared_domain ? @Rachael Dawn

Comment: It'll reboot the whole machine

Comment: If you are not an admin on that remote machine ("*I'm not sudoed*"), then it's unlikely that you have permission to reboot it...or to do anything else that would fix your connection problem. Ask an admin on that machine for assistance.

Comment: Being in the sudoers file and being able to run a command are two separate issues. If there is only OP on the machine being served in any way, it's likely that there are no permissions blocking them from running a reboot. Inversely, it would be irresponsible of a host to allow reboot access on shared servers.

Comment: If you don't have `sudo` privileges on the server there is no way you should be able to reboot the server and crash all users' work. If it's your own server then you should give yourself `sudo` privileges but then you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place. Even if I could figure out a way to reboot a server and crash all the users connected, I wouldn't post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to reboot a system without `sudo` or physical access. However, I think you can reboot from a GUI. If you are using x11 on the server, first enable x11 forwarding in your ssh config file. Then you can follow [this](https://linuxhint.com/linux_graphical_windows_x11_forwarding/) guide on your windows machine and it should work. You might need to install the xauth package so that might be a problem if you don't have `sudo` access.

Comment: and even if you can't shut down this way it should allow you to have a remote desktop.